# jQuery closest class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Level2">Click me</div>
    <div class="Level3">Information</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Level2">Click me</div>
    <div class="Level3">Information</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Level2">Click me</div>
    <div class="Level3">Information</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Level2">Click me</div>
    <div class="Level3">Information</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.Level2').click(function(){
   $('.Level2').closest('.Level3').fadeToggle();
});
```

I wanted to select the closest level3 to fadeIn and fadeOut, but doesn't work. Is my syntax wrong? online Sample :http://jsfiddle.net/meEUZ/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try `.next()` instead of `.closest()` that traverses through the ancestors of the DOM element.

[**Working Demo**](http://codepen.io/rishabhp/pen/bgZBML)

Also you should use `$(this)` rather than `$('.Level2')` else it'll select ALL the `.Level2` rather than the clicked one.

You can also go for something like this - `$(this).closest('.wrap').find('.Level3').fadeToggle();`.

Comment: The answer's demo link isn't working properly. please try https://jsfiddle.net/o3h0m4ra/

Comment: awesome, this answer helped me.

Answer (score 19):

jQuery's [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method doesn't select sibling selectors, but parents. Looks like you're looking for the [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method.

```
$('.Level2').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.Level3').fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: In my case `.find()` did the job.

Answer (score 8):

closest travels up the dom tree.  it won't find something thats a sibling.  you can use a find on a parent to achieve this

```
$('.Level2').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find('.Level3').fadeToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, There are many method avaiable in Jquery to find closest of the **DOM** element

```js
$('.Level1').click(function(){
   $(this).next('.Level3').fadeToggle();
});
$('.Level2').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.Level3').fadeToggle();

});
$('.Level4').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.Level3').fadeToggle(); 
});

$('.Level5').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.Level3').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.level{background:Red;width:200px;height:40px;}
.Level3{background:blue;width:300px;height:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Level1 level">Click me()sing next)</div>
    <div class="Level3">Information</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Level2 level">Click me(Using closest)</div>
    <div class="Level3">Information</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Level4 level">Click me(Usingh Parent)</div>
    <div class="Level3">Information</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Level5 level">Click me(Using Sibiling)</div>
    <div class="Level3">Information</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! `closest` starts the DOM search from the selector you pass to it, and goes upwards the DOM hierarchy, searching through the parents/ancestors. Use `siblings` or `next` instead.
Like this:

```
$('.Level2').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.Level3').fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a clear idea from the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".add").on("click", function () {
            var v = $(this).closest(".division").find("input[name='roll']").val();
            alert(v);
        });
    });
</script>
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo'<div class = "division">'
        . '<form method="POST" action="">'
        . '<p><input type="number" name="roll" placeholder="Enter Roll"></p>'
        . '<p><input type="button" class="add" name = "submit" value = "Click"></p>'
        . '</form></div>';
}
?>
```