# jquery closest returns undefined if apply on class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

While running following jquery code i am constantly getting 'undefined' in alert box. If i replace class="back" with id="back" and reflect same in jquery code , it works fine. But i am in situation such that closest need to be of class not an id. How to resolve this?

HTML :

```
<div id="up">
  <div id="boom">
  <div class="back">  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($(".back").closest("div").attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: there may be multiple element with class back

Comment: Check what elements `$(".back")` returns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery closest class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051196/jquery-closest-class-selector)

Comment: @PranavCBalan No , there aren't. Whatever you see above is the code. Except above there is only html,head tag with jquery file include.

Comment: @dfsq it returns [object Object]

Comment: @JoneDotosvky :  try `alert($(".back").closest("div[id]").attr("id"));`

Comment: You need to learn how to debug code. Are you using alert to inspect collection so it returns `[object Object]`? Use `console.log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.closest` starts from the current node. But this node haven't got `id` attribute.
You need to change the selector in in `.closest` as this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('.back').closest('div[id]').attr('id'));
});
```

Now you are searching for a `div` which has `id` as an attribute.

Comment: What if, he gives the current element an id?

Comment: Then he can use `.parents` instead of `.closest`

Comment: @Marii Your solution works but i didn't get the explanation of why 'div[id]' and not just 'div'

Comment: @Jone, div[id] means find that ancestor node which must have id attribute. Since the current div does not have, hence it finds successfully the 'boom' div

Comment: @JoneDotosvky, look at this: https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 0):

that is because your

```
<div class="back">
```

doesn't have id attribute so it will be undefined, check with

```
.attr("class")
```

it will return class name

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert($(".back").parents("div").attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` method checks from the current node, so if you want to find the first anchester(parent) div tag of the `class = "back"` then it should not be the div tag so you need to change the div tag to span or other tags

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($(".back").closest("div").attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="up">
  <div id="boom">
    <span class="back">  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working if i don't give span and use just div.

Comment: that because you are passing div[id] in closest() add id in class="back" div and test your code